# Fill List<T> with IEnumerable<T> when projecting a new type using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Here's my example code:

```
let departmentResult = 
// Where clause could go here...
.Select(department => new Department()
{
   Name = department["Name"].ToString(),
   // How can I fill Employees collection rather than replace it with a new list?
   Employees = new List<Employee>(employeesResult)
}
).FirstOrDefault()
```

In this example, I'm projecting a new Department class using LINQ. Department has an Employees (list of Employee) collection which I'm assigning by passing a separate LINQ query result to it (employeesResult).

The problem with this approach is Department's constructor assigns an event handler to its Employees collection. By assigning a new list of Employee to Employees, rather than iteratively adding Employee objects to Employees, it "clears" my event handler, as the new list doesn't have any event handlers assigned. I can re-add my event handler in Employees' setter, but now I have to have to add event handlers in two places.

Isn't there a way to do this:

```
let departmentResult = 
// Where clause goes here
.Select(department => new Department()
{
Name = department["Name"].ToString(),
// Possible solution: Subclass List<T> and add an AddMany method? This throws an error, though. 
// Error: Employees not found.
Employees.AddMany(employeesResult)
}
).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Define the setter of `Employees` to do the work.

Comment: Please show the code of this event that is the problem. It might be better to fix it on that end instead of this end.

Comment: What type is `department`. By the looks of it it is a dictionary of sorts. Also what stops you from creating a parameterized constructor that takes [department,employeesResult] as it's arguments. That way you can handle initialization internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can, add a constructor parameter.  After all, if the constructor is already creating an empty list and attaching an event handler, then it should also be able to create a populated list.

```
.Select(department => new Department(department["Name"].ToString(), employeesResult))
```

If you can't add constructor parameters, then simply define a factory method.

```
.Select(department => CreateDepartment(department["Name"].ToString(), employeesResult))

...

static Department CreateDepartment(string name, IEnumerable<Employee> employees)
{
  var department = new Department()
  {
    Name = name
  };

  foreach (var employee in employees)
  {
    department.Employees.Add(employee);
  }

  return department;
}
```

You could also expand the lambda into a code block, though preferably I like to put side-effecting code in separate methods (as in the previous example).

```
.Select(department => 
{
  var department = new Department()
  {
    Name = department["Name"].ToString()
  };

  foreach (var employee in employeesResult)
  {
    department.Employees.Add(employee);
  }

  return department;
})
```

Comment: Dave, thank you. The lambda code block solution is exactly what I'm looking for. This solution works best for me. I also appreciate your alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use AddRange,

```
let departmentResult = 
// Where clause goes here
.Select(department => 
{
   var x = new Department()
    {
        Name = department["Name"].ToString(),
        Employees = department.Employees
    }

   x.Employees.AddRange(employeesResult);
   return x;
}).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Arbitrary statements cannot be used in an object initializer.

Comment: Erti-Chris, thank you. Your solution also works, sans the Employees = department.Employees line (though this is probably due to my specific use case and not a problem with your code). Also, thanks for clueing me to AddRange -- I can drop my custom "AddMany" method now. :)